# I'd like to create a batch file with certain rules

Tags: batch-file

Hi I would like to create a bat file that executes the following commands:

```
avr-gcc -Os -DF_CPU=16000000UL -mmcu=atmega328p -c -o battery.o battery.c
avr-gcc -mmcu=atmega328p battery.o -o battery
avr-objcopy -O ihex -R .eeprom battery battery.hex
avrdude -C "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr\etc\avrdude.conf" -v -p ATMEGA328P -c arduino -P COM4 -b 57600 -U flash:w:battery.hex:i
```

I've ran this as a bat but the commands aren't recognized. Should I move to the directories that has the executables first? 
The second command always throw an error in a msgbox that doesn't really matter, can it 'ok' the msgbox by itself and carry on to the next command?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

Why would you expect that to work. It will work if the batch file is in same directory as the files.

**ALWAYS SPECIFY FULL PATHS**

```
%windir%\system32\setx
```

is one way to do it, above is same as

```
C:\Windows\system32\setx
```